# What is the difference between these three

Tags: grammar

> 1. If the demand has increased, price will also increase.
> 2. If the demand increases, price will also increase.
> 3. If the demand increases, price also increases.

Answer (score 1):

> If the demand has increased, price will also increase.

If, the the past, the demand increased, that will cause the price to increase in the future.

> If the demand increases, price will also increase.

(If and) when the demand increases, that will cause the price to increase in the future.

> If the demand increases, price also increases.

(If and) when the demand increases, that will cause the price to increase.

Let me know if that's not broken-up enough.

Comment: You mean 2 and 3 mean the same?

Comment: @user236989 Almost. 3 means that the two are tied together: an increase in demand directly causes an immediate increase in price. 2 means that when demand increases, price will increase, but not always immediately. They are effectually the same though. 2's wording would be rarely used in casual English.

Comment: But internet says there are only 3 three types of conditional http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/if.htm  so first one is 'if the demand has increased' is unidiomatic i guess

Comment: @user236989 oh, I guess it is. I didn't even notice that, nice catch, mixing `has` with `will` doesn't really work there.